# Play video with phone built-in video player

Tags: android, button, video, hyperlink

I have a simple button, and I wish to play an URL video (xxx.mp4) by clicking on this button but without a videoView or webView. So if I click on the button , the phone will ask which internal player I'll choose to play the video.

Button to play video: button3

Video link: http://wisdom.gotdns.com/application/android/res/00/1112PJ12.mp4

**cv_1112pj12.java**

```
package com.schkop.project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class cv_1112pj12 extends Activity {
    Button bn0, bn1, bn2, bn3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cv_1112pj12);

        //
        bn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
        bn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        bn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        bn0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent it0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                startActivity(it0);
            }

        });

        bn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent it1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Store.class);
                startActivity(it1);
            }

        });

        bn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent it2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), News_feed.class);
                startActivity(it2);
            }

        });

        bn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent it3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cv_1112pj12_play.class);
                startActivity(it3);
            }

        });

        //

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**cv_1112pj12.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e9e9e9"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/tab1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/tab2"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" 
        android:background="#2f4444"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/tab3"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#2f4444"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#e9e9e9"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#e9e9e9"
        android:src="@drawable/cv_1112pj12"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#e9e9e9"
        android:text="@string/tab2_1112pj12"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#e9e9e9"
        android:text="@string/tab2_1112pj12_desc"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#e9e9e9"
        android:text="@string/tab_space"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#e9e9e9"
        android:text="@string/tab2_noti"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#e9e9e9"
        android:text="@string/tab2_noti_desc"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#2f4444"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="@string/tab2_watch" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the xml and java file, what code should I add into these file? And please post all the codes when comment (not only the correction part), thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for playing video.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(sampleFile), "video/mp4");
        startActivity(intent);
```

sampleFile is your url for video.

Comment: Here is some errors:

-intent cannot be resolved ; Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation ; Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement ; The method parse(String) in the type Uri is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: Plz post your entire log cat error and also code at which you get this error.